# Plotting multiple boxplots with facet_wrap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have multiple genomic datasets about a cancer drug. The datasets are genes as rows, and samples as columns. Each dataset contains two labels, either the samples are `Response` or `NoResponse`.

Now, I want to compare the expression of a certain gene, between the `Response` and `NoResponse` groups, in each dataset individually. So the aim is that for each dataset (17 datasets overall), check if this gene is more expressed in the `Response` group, or the `NoResponse` group.

I aim to accomplish this by boxplot, using `facet_wrap` to indluce all boxplots in a one beautiful plot.

##### I'm having some trouble with that. Here is my code:

```
facetplot = gene_data %>% ggplot(aes(response, expr, fill = dataSet)) + facet_wrap(~dataSet) + 
  labs(x = 'Clinical outcome', y = 'Expression')

boXplots = facetplot + geom_boxplot()
boXplots
```

I want for each boxplot in the x-axis to be the response status, and the y-axis would be the expression of the gene, and the seperation of each boxplot would be according to the dataset number.

##### This is a small piece of `gene_data` (this data is only for one gene that I chose, and it is showing samples from two datasets only, there are many more):

Each row is a sample, and you can see if the sample is Response or NoResponse, the gene expression, and to which dataset it belongs:

```
structure(list(expr = c("4.85031051647344", "1.53115160697977", 
"12.8658881083245", "4.14991129619867", "6.38097000693584", "6.58995340312141", 
"1.65500966263632", "7.12750090336409", "7.8996385796547", "7.53055682033225", 
"2.22223448360773", "8.62758918096156", "3.48119701276203", "4.62943147571301", 
"1.6616090122057", "2.10752212028492", "2.93218579193446", "8.14568475132326", 
"13.727187056092", "3.03615586961175", "1.47868321205503", "0.486794162731451", 
"2.75214758543253", "10.9209245057866", "9.81523416851324", "9.50620285828924", 
"3.68894217900121", "7.99157365749216", "8.8075894831211", "2.86402639322666", 
"6.80932382802606", "1.79652586144352", "4.18170107440015", "1.56494417900127", 
"1.08588972884479", "2.31307162334035", "7.96791632540018", "0.286524861392658", 
"5.73084282827411", "4.83366231978411", "4.51736060497412", "1.89103336082304", 
"0.905882528456541", "4.24561453086179", "10.2744119421325", 
"1.80851597851749", "7.85173352142177", "3.74385424752237", "1.40594503311156", 
"32.95255", "32.42297", "30.17676", "29.0926", "32.06051", "31.80172", 
"31.38914", "32.00126", "31.83038", "31.97847", "28.4888", "30.99362", 
"29.11862", "30.76407", "31.59104", "30.68113", "31.96988", "29.31726", 
"30.98914", "29.66506", "29.89776", "31.35337", "29.90499", "32.16743", 
"31.22215", "32.12123", "31.78393", "30.11914", "29.54727", "31.75156", 
"30.99448", "31.48003", "32.42661", "33.24433", "32.11272", "30.89568", 
"28.33333", "30.87174", "32.07811", "31.05286", "30.6044", "31.62753", 
"32.33149", "29.67083", "31.75701", "29.73103", "31.03143", "30.83465", 
"27.53271", "33.15345", "31.47515"), response = c("NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "Response", "Response", 
"NoResponse", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"Response", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "Response", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "Response", "NoResponse", "Response", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "Response", "Response", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "Response", "Response", "NoResponse", "Response", 
"NoResponse", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "Response", 
"Response", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "Response", 
"Response", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "Response", 
"Response", "Response", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "Response", "Response", 
"NoResponse", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse"), dataSet = c("data1", 
"data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", 
"data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", 
"data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", 
"data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", 
"data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", 
"data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", 
"data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data2", 
"data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", 
"data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", 
"data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", 
"data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", 
"data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", 
"data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", 
"data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", "data2", 
"data2")), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

##### My code is producing this weird output:

[image]

##### Wanted output - something like this, where the blue boxes are for `Response` and the red are for `NoResponse`:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that your expression values are strings. They need to be numeric. Most likely the conversion occurred when data was read into R, so you should figure out why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @neilws comment, the expression values are strings that need to be changed to numeric:

```
gene_data$expr = as.numeric(as.character(gene_data$expr))
```

And to match the example given you would need to change `fill` to *response*

```
ggplot(gene_data,aes(response, expr, fill = response)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~dataSet) + 
  labs(x = 'Clinical outcome', y = 'Expression')
```

[image: Here is the output]